# Desafio de Jquery _ Ordenador de serie

Tags: jquery

Desearía saber como podría hacer la animacion del enunciado, si es suficiente con jquery o seria pertinente usar otro framework?
**Enunciado:**

- Ingresar un conjunto indeterminado de números enteros en cualquier
  orden*.
- Una vez ingresado el conjunto de números :

  1. Generar la animación visual de dicho proceso.

Por ejemplo una vez ingresado el conjunto de números, la animación del ordenamiento luce como :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

***Teniendo en cuenta lo siguiente***

> - Los números ingresados no deben repetirse.

Comment: Esto es una tarea? cuantos puntos tiene de valor?

Comment: no es solo un desafio, solo quiero tips nada mas

Comment: analiza el método de burbuja y en base a eso lo resuelves fácil, lo detallado seria hacer la animación :D

Comment: Claro eso corresponde al algoritmo burbuja, pero lo que no consigo es la animacion, bueno yo supongo que todo ello entraria en un array , el asunto es animarlo con jquery, me parece que se podria usar otro framework

Comment: @Kpeski2814 te doy un consejo, aquí hay muchas personas expertas en jquery, trata de agregar lo que has tratado ya que es importante muestres has intentado algo, de lo contrarío tal vez tu pregunta sea cerrada... =( Se Valiente =)

Comment: me referia a otros framework como angular

Comment: Sí, es posible. Hasta se podría hacer de manera simple (más o menos) con JavaScript puro

Comment: Claro , pero el problema esta en  la animacion

Comment: Bajo mi punto de vista la librería más potente para estos casos es [GSAP](http://greensock.com/gsap) de GreenSock.

Comment: Gracias eso es lo que queria escuchar